# Petapoco - Couldn't find split point

Tags: c#, .net, database, orm, petapoco

I have been struggling with peta poco and related classes and are getting the error "Couldn't find split point between PetaPocoProofOfConcept.Resource and PetaPocoProofOfConcept.BookingType".

My two classes are:

```
[TableName("Resource"), PrimaryKey("Id")]
public class Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long MinTimeSpan { get; set; }
    public long MaxTimeSpan { get; set; }
    public long FixedTimeSpan { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActiveStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActiveEnd { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public BookingType BookingType { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
}

[TableName("BookingType"), PrimaryKey("Id")]
public class BookingType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I get the error when executing this line of code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var resources = new Database(connection).Query<Resource, BookingType>("SELECT * FROM [Resource]").ToList();
        }
```

I have been reading some documentation but cant seem to find any answer of why this fails. Does anyone know?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the way Petapoco multi mapping works.
You can use that syntax in this way:

```
var posts = db.Fetch<post, author>(@"
        SELECT * FROM posts 
        LEFT JOIN authors ON posts.author = authors.id ORDER BY posts.id
        ");
```

This gives you two list with Posts and Authors.

If you want to perform more complex mappings (like your example), you need to write a callback like this:

```
var posts = db.Fetch<post, author, post>(
        (p,a)=> { p.author_obj = a; return p; },
        @"SELECT * FROM posts 
        LEFT JOIN authors ON posts.author = authors.id ORDER BY posts.id
        ");
```

[More info on Petapoco Multi mapping](http://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/posts/115-PetaPoco-Mapping-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-One-Relationships)

Comment: Ahh okay, that expains a few things. I must have misunderstod how it works. I will try what you are suggesting here, thanks.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Does this really work? 
I tried exactly the same and have the problem that Id-Property of both entities is not set (=0).